# MySQL Using WHERE in LOAD DATA INFILE Statement From CSV/TXT

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a txt file that looks like:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3
1, foo0, bar0
1, foo1, bar1
2, foo2, bar2
3, foo3, bar3
```

And I want to import the txt file to a database using a similar query to:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/sample.txt'
INTO TABLE sample
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But only want records from the txt file where Col1 has a value of 1 and I only want to use Col1 and Col2 in the sample table. How would I create a query using a WHERE clause to determine that Col1's value is 1 and then only place the first two columns from the txt into the sample table?

Comment: Not via `LOAD DATA`. Why do not prepare file before? (using `sed`, for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at mysql load data infile syntax

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number LINES]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```

it doesn't seem like a where clause is supported. You're going to have to remove those unwanted records afterwards, or else do some form of command line filtering and then load the filtered data in mysql.